# How to access parent class from child class?

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to automate a form validation and db insertion process. In a particular part, I need to be able to access the parent class from the child class. To be exact, I need to access the parent class to access another child class.

I've tried to replicate the same structure I'm using in the actual code:

```
class Family {
    public function __construct($members = []) {
        foreach ($members as $member) {
            $this->$member[0] = new Member($member);
        }
    }
}
class Member {
    public $name;
    public $niisan;
    public function __construct($name = []) {
        $this->name = $name[0];
        if (count($name) > 1) {
            $this->get_niisan($name[1]);
        }
    }
    public function get_niisan($member_lookup) {
        $this->niisan = $this->name . " has a niisan named X";
    }
}

$Winchesters = new Family([
    ["Dean"],
    ["Sam", "Dean"],
]);
```

Output:

```
object(Family)#1 (2) {
    ["Dean"]    => object(Member)#2 (2) {
        ["name"]    => "Dean"
        ["niisan"]  => NULL
    }
    ["Sam"]     => object(Member)#3 (2) {
        ["name"]    => "Sam"
        ["niisan"]  => "Sam has a niisan named X"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create two subclasses in the main class. Order of the creation of subclasses matters. `["Sam"]` is dependant on `["Dean"]`, so `["Dean"]` needs to be created first. Some of the properties of `["Dean"]` will be used in `["Sam"]`.

In JavaScript, I'd write it like this:

```
function Family(members) {
    var parent = this; // Family object
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        // passing a reference of Family to the new Member object
        // so that it can access the main object later
        this[members[i][0]] = new Member(parent, members[i]);
    }
}

function Member(parent, name) {
    // saving the reference to the parent object
    this.parent = parent;
    this.name = name[0];
    this.niisan = "";
    this.get_niisan = function (lookup) {
        // accessing the parent object and then getting the name property of "Dean" object
        this.niisan = this.name + " has a niisan named " + this.parent[lookup].name;
    };
    if (name.length > 1) {
        this.get_niisan(name[1]);
    }
}

var Winchesters = new Family([
    ["Dean"],
    ["Sam", "Dean"]
]);
```

Passing the main object to each sub-object. PHP must have its own way to deal with this. I just don't know it.

---

**Update:** For the down/close-voter: How is this unclear?

I have two classes: Family and Member. Member class is initialized inside the Family class. Following code

```
$Winchesters = new Family([
    ["Dean"],
    ["Sam", "Dean"],
]);
```

results in:

```
object(Family)#1 (2) {
    ["Dean"]    => object(Member)#2 (2) {
        ["name"]    => "Dean"
        ["niisan"]  => NULL
    }
    ["Sam"]     => object(Member)#3 (2) {
        ["name"]    => "Sam"
        ["niisan"]  => "Sam has a niisan named X"
    }
}
```

At runtime, first a `Member` with the name "Dean" is created and assigned to a variable `Dean` inside `Family`.
Second, `Member` "Sam" is created, but `Sam` is dependant on the first created object, `Dean`. `Sam` needs to access the parent class `Family`, and then access to `Dean`, and get the property `name` and use it in assigning `niisan` variable.

Please check the JavaScript example. I want to mimic the exact functionality in PHP. Pass the main class to the child class so that the child class can access the later-created variables inside the main class.

Comment: `parent::methodname`

Comment: @Farkie I'll be accessing a sub-class in the main class. How should I implement `parent::methodname` in a way which will make this line work `$this->niisan = $this->name . " has a niisan named " . parent::$member_lookup->name;`?

Comment: `$this->$member[0] = new Member($member);` overwrites the same element of the `member` array each time. Also, it should be `$this->member`, not `$this->$member`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminology is confusing. In PHP OOP, *parent* and *child* usually refer to relationships between classes that inherit from each other, not the objects of those classes (C++ calls them *base* and *derived* class, and Javascript uses prototype chains for parent classes).

What you need to do is store a reference to the `Family` in the `Member` class.

```
class Member {
    public $name;
    public $niisan;
    public $family;

    public function __construct($name = [], $family) {
        $this->family = $family;
        $this->name = $name[0];
        if (count($name) > 1) {
            $this->get_niisan($name[1]);
        }
    }
    public function get_niisan($member_lookup) {
        $this->niisan = $this->name . " has a niisan named X";
    }
}

class Family {
    public function __construct($members = []) {
        foreach ($members as $member) {
            $this->$member[0] = new Member($member, $this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if the `Member` class wants to access siblings, it can use `$this->family` to get the containing family.

BTW, using variable-named properties in `Family` is poor design, IMHO. Instead, you should use a single `$member` property containing an associative array:

```
$this->members = array();
foreach ($members as $member) {
    $this->members[$member[0]] = new Member($member, $this);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks again, Barmar. I'm not really familiar with classes and all. I mainly code in JavaScript. Having problems from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

> In a particular part, I need to be able to access the parent class
>   from the child class. To be exact, I need to access the parent class
>   to access another child class.

You can't access another child class from a parent class.  Only the child can access the parent. In your example, you haven't created any kind of inheritance.  This is how you create inheritance in PHP.

```
class FooParent {
    public function display($text) {
        echo $text;
    }
}

class Foo extends FooParent {
    public function someMethod() {

        // ask the parent to display the text
        parent::display("Hello World!");
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->someMethod();
```

Which would display "Hello World!".  Hopefully this will help you get started, to learn more about PHP's version of OOP - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: He's not really talking about parent classes, he's talking about relationships in the container hierarchy.

Comment: @Barmar Nice catch...I was thrown by his terminology and the first comment which answered with parent::method...up voted your answer.